# math module not working in a string for eval

Tags: python, math, formula, eval

Suppose I have this code:

```
import math
import traceback


def getValue(s,p,val):
    d={}
    for k in range(len(p)):
        d[p[k]]=val[k]

    y = eval(s,d)
    return str(round(y,3))

values = [5,3]
parameters = ['var1','var2']
s = 'var2*3/2 + math.log(100)-var1**2'
x = getValue(s,parameters,values)
 print x
```

but I only get this error:
**NameError**: name 'math' is not defined

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you launch it? If you do it like a executable batch file and you're on Linux, you should add shebang for python (or python3)

Comment: For now I'm launching it on Wing IDE, windows, and I have this at first line: #!/usr/bin/env python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to `eval`, if present, should reference the global namespace. Here, you explicitely assigned an empty dict to it, so you don't have any access to the name `math` of the global namespace. You could assign `d` to the local namespace of `eval` instead:

```
import math
import traceback


def getValue(s,p,val):
    d = {}
    for k in range(len(p)):
        d[p[k]]=val[k]

    y = eval(s, globals(), d)
    return str(round(y,3))

values = [5,3]
parameters = ['var1','var2']
s = 'var2*3/2 + math.log(100)-var1**2'
x = getValue(s,parameters,values)
print(x)
# -15.895
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add `math` symbol to the `globals` parameter of the `eval` call.

```
values = [5,3, math]
parameters = ['var1','var2','math']
```

Please be aware that `eval` usage with arbitrary input is dangerous.

Comment: About eval dangerousness, I only want to use it on dynamic math formulas, with dynamic parameters. Are there better solutions?

Comment: Make sure you understand the risks. It is OK for trusted input (like in a utility for personal use only). It cannot be made secure for arbitrary input. There is plenty of information about this topic, lots of it here on SO.